# Ansible parses strings as lists if the format is compatible, how to escape?

Tags: ansible

Using ansible, I need to put a list of hosts in line in a file like so:

```
["127.0.0.1", "127.0.0.2", "127.0.0.3"]
```

But whenever I achieve this format, ansible interprets it as a list and the content of the file is this pythonic version:

```
['127.0.0.1', '127.0.0.2', '127.0.0.3']
```

Here's my attempts to get it out thus far:

```
---

- hosts: all
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:

  - set_fact:
      myhosts:
        - 127.0.0.1
        - 127.0.0.2
        - 127.0.0.3

  # This comes out as a list, I need a string
  - set_fact:
      var: "[ \"{{ myhosts | join('\", \"')}}\" ]"
  - debug: var=var

  # This comes out as a string, but I need no underscore on it
  - set_fact:
      var: "_[ \"{{ myhosts | join('\", \"')}}\" ]"
  - debug: var=var

  # This also comes out as a list
  - set_fact:
      var: >
        [ "{{ myhosts | join('", "')}}" ]
  - debug: var=var

  # Also parsed as a list
  - set_fact:
      var: "{{ myhosts | to_json }}"
  - debug: var=var

# ansible-playbook -i "localhost," this_file.yml
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some filters that prevent Ansible template engine from doing string evaluation.
This list of filters is stored in [STRING_TYPE_FILTERS](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/constants.py#L326) setting.
In Ansible 2.1 it contains: `string`, `to_json`, `to_nice_json`, `to_yaml`, `ppretty`, `json`.

So, you can do this:

```
- lineinfile: line="{{ myhosts | to_json }}" dest=output.txt
```

This will add `["127.0.0.1", "127.0.0.2", "127.0.0.3"]` line to the file.

And don't believe `debug`'s output when dealing with exact string formatting.
Always use `copy: content="{{ string_output_to_test | string }}" dest=test.txt` and check file contents to be sure.

`debug: var=myvar` will always template with evaluation, so your string will always be printed as a list.
`debug: msg="{{ myvar | string }}"` will print `myvar` as JSON encoded string.