# Provision a JSON file with Ansible while keeping indentation

Tags: json, ansible

I want to provision a JSON file with Ansible. The content of this file is a variable in my Ansible's playbook.

And very important for my usecase: **I need the indentation & line breaks to be exactly the same as in my variable**.

The variable looks like this :

```
my_ansible_var: 
  {
    "foobar": {
      "foo": "bar"
    },
    "barfoo": {
      "bar": "foo"
    }
  }
```

And it's use like this in my playbook :

```
- name: drop the gitlab-secrets.json file
  copy: 
    content: "{{ my_ansible_var }}"
    dest: "/some/where/file.json"
```

**Problem:** when this tasks is played, my file is provisionned but as a "one-line" file:

```
{ "foobar": { "foo": "bar" }, "barfoo": { "bar": "foo" } }
```

I tried several other ways:

- Retrieve the `base64` value of my JSON content, and use `content: "{{ my_ansible_var | b64decode }}"` : same problem at the end
- I tried playing with [YAML block indicator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790454/in-yaml-how-do-i-break-a-string-over-multiple-lines/21699210#21699210) : none of the block indicators helped me with that problem
- I tried adding [some filters](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter) like `to_json`, `to_nice_json(indent=2)` : no more luck here

## Question:

How in Ansible can I provison a JSON file while keeping the exact indentation I want ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In your example `my_ansible_var` is a dict. If you don't need to access its keys in your playbook (e.g. `my_ansible_var.foobar.foo`) and just want it as JSON string for your `copy` task, force it to be a string.
2. There is type-detection feature in Ansible template engine, so if you feed it with dict-like or list-like string, it will be evaluated into object. See some details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40114409/ansible-parses-strings-as-lists-if-the-format-is-compatible-how-to-escape/40116151#40116151).

This construction will work ok for your case:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    my_ansible_var: |
      {
        "foobar": {
          "foo": "bar"
        },
        "barfoo": {
          "bar": "foo"
        }
      }
  tasks:
    - copy:
        content: "{{ my_ansible_var | string }}"
        dest: /tmp/out.json
```

Note vertical bar in `my_ansible_var` definition and `| string` filter in `content` expression.

Comment: Thanks, it works as expected. I was misunderstanding the way I was declaring/using my variable