# Prevent Ansible to reorder the URI json post in alphabetical

Tags: ansible

I try to communicate with zabbix API with ansible. It waits for a json input and process it, however, it does not work. My playbook task looks like this:

```
- name: Login to zabbix
  uri:
    url: https://{{ zabbix_server_ip }}/api_jsonrpc.php
    method: POST
    validate_certs: false
    body:
      jsonrpc: 2.0
      method: user.login
      params:
        user: admin
        password: XXX
      id: 1
      auth: null
    body_format: json
  register: zabbix_login
```

If I run the playbook with `-vvvv` then I see what was posted to the API by ansible. The interesting part looks like this:

```
        "body": {
            "auth": null,
            "id": 1,
            "jsonrpc": 2.0,
            "method": "user.login",
            "params": {
                "password": "XXX",
                "user": "admin"
            }
```

Which is correct, the same should be posted, but `zabbix_login` remains empty from the API answer, because of this error message (also parsed from `-vvvv`):

```
"json": {
    "error": {
        "code": -32600,
        "data": "Invalid parameter \"/jsonrpc\": a character string is expected.",
        "message": "Invalid Request."
    },
    "id": 1,
    "jsonrpc": "2.0"
},
```

I belive the problem should be that the API wants `jsonrpc: 2.0` parameter at the beginning of the request, as it's documentation described it. But it seems ansible reordering the json request somehow to alphabetical order. How do I prevent this?

I already read this question: [How to prevent Ansible from re-ordering JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073794/how-to-prevent-ansible-from-re-ordering-json) and also the answer, but it just reorders the answer for the request. I need to keep the same order of the request, as wrote in the playbook.

Comment: It's not that it wants a json key "at the beginning," it's that it wants `"jsonrpc": "2.0"` as one can see in its response payload to you. Merely quote the `: 2.0` (as `: '2.0'`) to keep it from being sent as a number

Comment: @mdaniel you're right. The strange thing is that it worked before, I thought that the zabbix update made it more strict. Based on your comment, I checked that the PHP upgrade spoiled it. Anyway, thank you for the point. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comment, I fixed the playbook and quoted every input.

```
- name: Login to zabbix
  uri:
    url: https://{{ zabbix_server_ip }}/api_jsonrpc.php
    method: POST
    validate_certs: false
    body:
      jsonrpc: '2.0'
      method: 'user.login'
      params:
        user: 'admin'
        password: 'XXX'
      id: '1'
      auth: null
    body_format: json
  register: zabbix_login
```

It seems it is fixed the issue.